# which class have body of connection method in jdbc

Tags: java

Java Question

the class is where ? which has the body (declaration) of all methods (Like : connection, getConnection() etc.).

name of that class and where is situated

Comment: When using Sun's Jdbc-Odbc driver, the driver class used is `sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver` and all Jdbc classes are located within `sun.jdbc.odbc.*` `JdbcOdbcConnection`, for example.

Answer (score 3):

The `Connection` class is an abstract class in `java.sql.Connection`. For a specific DB, this is extended by the DB implementation itself, so it should be in the JAR file that accompanies your specific database.

Normaly you shouldn't need to know where it is or how it is implemented, as you should only use the interfaces provided by Java.

Answer (score 1):

JDBC, which contains `Connection`, `Statement`, etc. objects, is an API that defines how to connect to a database from Java.

As an API, it can have several implementations. In this case, implementations are JDBC Drivers provided by database vendors (Oracle, MySQL, DB2, PostgreSQL,...).